# How to group clusters with semantic similarity?

Tags: python, clustering, semantic-similarity

I have a list of job titles. I found the semantic similarity between them by using `word2vec` in `spacy`.

Now I want job titles which have more than 83% similarity be in the same cluster. For example I have:

```
titles=[art teacher, gym teacher, basketball teacher, painting teacher]
art_teacher=[1, 0.7,0.6,0.91] 
gym_teacher=[0.7,1, 0.9,0.5]
basketball_teacher=[0.6, 0.9,1,0.55]
painting_teacher=[0.91,0.5,0.55,1]
```

I want names that have more than 85% similarity to be clustered together, so we would have:

`cluster1: art teacher , painting teacher`

`cluster2: basketball teacher, gym teacher`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There might already be a built-in function to compare these outputs you've shown, but one solution would be to just threshold the lists into `Boolean lists`, and then use `logical_and` to compare them:

```
import numpy as np

def threshold_clusters(teacher_list, threshold = 0.85):
    return [i>threshold for i in teacher_list]

def compare_clusters(first,second):
    first = threshold_clusters(first)
    second = threshold_clusters(second)
    return np.logical_and(first, second).any()

print(compare_clusters(teacher,gym_teacher))
print(compare_clusters(teacher,basketball_teacher))
print(compare_clusters(teacher,painting_teacher))
print(compare_clusters(gym_teacher,basketball_teacher))
print(compare_clusters(gym_teacher,painting_teacher))
print(compare_clusters(basketball_teacher,painting_teacher))
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Otherwise please accept the answer